# Unsupported URL Error on iPod

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, jailbreak

I have an iPod touch 4th generation Jailbroken 5.0.1, and today I started getting this "unsupported URL" error within apps, and on the home screen safari shortcuts. I have noticed that the url's start with "o" so it looks like "ohttp://". I have no idea how to fix this so any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I figured it out with the help of

http://www.iphoneforums.net/forum/iphone-help-15/unsupported-url-after-limera1n-jailbreak-4114/

When I had reset all settings on my iPod to fix my YouTube app, it turned browser changer back on.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please mark this as the correct answer if it's what helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I will in 12 hours